# Extract First Character (allowing for extra grouping)

Tags: characters, strings, xstring

I would like to extract the first character. Using `xstring`'s `\StrChar` works fine for simple cases. However, when the paramter has an additional brace group, I need some expansion magic to get that to work.

My naive attemps to 1) Test the first char with `\IfBeginWith{#1}{\{}{}{}` and 2) use `\fullexpandarg` didn't resolve this issue.

The MWE below produces

[image]

where as rhe desired output is `a` for both cases.

### Related Questions:

- [Extract first character of string stored in macro using Expl3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/402835/4301)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand*{\ExtractFirstChar}[1]{%
    %% #1 = string to extract first char from
    %\fullexpandarg
    %\IfBeginWith{#1}{\{}{%
    %    \StrChar{#1}{2}[\FirstChar]%
    %}{%
        \StrChar{#1}{1}[\FirstChar]%
    %}%
    First char of '#1' is '\FirstChar'\par
}

\begin{document}
  \ExtractFirstChar{abc}
  \ExtractFirstChar{{a,b,c}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: {a,b,c} IS the first token.  `\detokenize{#1}` gives an interesting result, but not `a`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Hmmm, that would make an interesting question. But, I don't want the first token, I want the first character.

Comment: what is the first character of `{\'{e}abc}` or  `{éfg}` or `\textbf{x}yz` or `\hspace{1em}xyz` ?  neither "first" nor "character" are well defined terms here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Good point. But `\StrRemoveBraces` seems to work for my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the `\StrRemoveBraces` before `\StrChar`:

```
\newcommand*{\ExtractFirstChar}[1]{%
    \StrRemoveBraces{#1}[\FirstChar]%
    \StrChar{\FirstChar}{1}[\FirstChar]%
    First char of '#1' is '\FirstChar'\par
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). Thanks for that. I was not aware of `StrRemoveBraces` as it is not listed in the Chapter 2. I should have read the remainer of the document.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your input only contains (non TeX special) ASCII characters and braces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\firstchar}{sm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \grill_firstchar:V #2
   }
   {
    \grill_firstchar:n { #2 }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \grill_firstchar:n
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { \tl_count_tokens:f { \tl_head:n { #1 } } > 1 }
   {% we have to redo
    \grill_firstchar:f { \tl_head:n { #1 } }
   }
   {% just one token
    \tl_head:n { #1 }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_count_tokens:n { f }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \grill_firstchar:n { V, f }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\firstchar{abc} should print ``a''

\firstchar{{a,b,c}} should print ``a''

\firstchar{{{a},b,c}} should print ``a''

\newcommand\test{{{a}},b,c}

\edef\result{\firstchar*{\test}} \result\ should print ``a''

\end{document}
```

[image]